# MeteorJS & mongo binary imagefile

Tags: mongodb, meteor, base64, png

Can we use in MeteorJS binary inserted png to the mongodb ? Or do we have to stick base64 ?

I inserted tons of binary png to mongodg for saving the spaces.

I can perfectly utilize it from my C++ codes.

But now need some web frontend.

Answer (score 1):

There are packages like `ostrio:files` that will do a lot of the work for you. Inserting files into the database works, but puts a load on the database and app to do basic file serving activity, which is better done by something like AWS S3.

Alternatively there is a great service called Filestack https://www.filestack.com/ which is very easy to integrate to, and has a good upload control complete with cropping and resizing. You can just store the image URL's in your database. Quick to implement, and offloads from your server.